# Ruby - prevent GzipWriter from adding metadata onto its header

Tags: ruby, gzip

I need to encode a file such that, if the content of the file is the same, then its encoded version is the same too.

The file I need to encode, `config.yml`, contains the following string:

`This is my secret setup file`

My code is as follows:

```
require 'stringio'
require 'base64'
require 'zlib'

my_text = File.read('config.yml')
wio = StringIO.new('W')
w_gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(wio)
w_gz.mtime = 0 # Specify the modification time (mtime) in the gzip header
w_gz.orig_name = 'userdata' # Specify the original name (str) in the gzip header
w_gz.write(my_text)
w_gz.close
puts Base64.encode64(wio.string)
```

At the time when `Base64` renders the encoded string, the string must be the exact same if the content of `config.yml` is the same. However some metadata seems to be added which makes it impossible to get the same `Base64`-encoded string, example:

First run of the script:

> H4sIC**Go**Am1kAA3VzZXJkYXRhAAvJyCxWAKLcSoXi1OSi1BIgVVJaoJCWmZPK
>   BQAdlUQpHQAAAA==

Seconds later:

> H4sIC**G4**Am1kAA3VzZXJkYXRhAAvJyCxWAKLcSoXi1OSi1BIgVVJaoJCWmZPK
>   BQAdlUQpHQAAAA==

Minutes later:

> H4sIC**GkB**m1kAA3VzZXJkYXRhAAvJyCxWAKLcSoXi1OSi1BIgVVJaoJCWmZPK
>   BQAdlUQpHQAAAA==

Comment: it seems like this would be unavoidable since GzipWriter uses the zlib library. Try creating a gzip file using the command-line and see if the encoding is the same. My feeling is that it will never be the same because compressing a file is a fundamentally new operation. You should also try to compare the MD5 or SHA1 hashes generated to see if they differ.

Comment: @RudolfOlah If the strings differ then the hashes should differ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to set `mtime` to `0` seems to be ignored. Using an arbitrary value of `1000000000` or even `1` doesn't cause it to shift.

I think this is because the Gzip library is C-based and 0 is considered false, not assigned, and so is overruled.

The [Gzip RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) is pretty short and there's not much metadata in there:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |ID1|ID2|CM |FLG|     MTIME     |XFL|OS | (more-->)
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just manually replace the 5th through 8th bytes (indices 4..7) of the compressed result with zeros. This sets mtime to zero, indicating no time set per the RFC. There does not appear to be a way to get Ruby's class to do this for you.